# Calculate Smith Normal Form of matrix

Tags: matrices, smith-normal-form

I am struggling to calculate the Smith Normal Form of this matrix. I know it is wrong because I checked on a computer. Can someone help me where I am going wrong?

$\begin{bmatrix}
6&2&3&0\\
2&3&-4&1\\
-3&3&1&2\\
-1&2&-3&5
\end{bmatrix}\implies
\begin{bmatrix}
0&6&2&3\\
1&2&3&-4\\
2&-3&3&1\\
5&-1&2&-3
\end{bmatrix}\implies
\begin{bmatrix}
1&2&3&-4\\
0&6&2&3\\
2&-3&3&1\\
5&-1&2&-3
\end{bmatrix}\implies
\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&0&0\\
0&6&2&3\\
2&-7&-3&9\\
5&-11&-13&17
\end{bmatrix}\implies
\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&0&0\\
0&6&2&3\\
0&-7&-3&9\\
0&-11&-13&17
\end{bmatrix}\implies
\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&0&0\\
0&2&3&6\\
0&-3&9&-7\\
0&-13&17&-11
\end{bmatrix}\implies
\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&0&0\\
0&2&3&0\\
0&-3&9&2\\
0&-13&17&28
\end{bmatrix}\implies
\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&0&0\\
0&2&1&0\\
0&-3&12&2\\
0&-13&30&-50
\end{bmatrix}\implies
\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&0&0\\
0&1&0&0\\
0&0&-27&2\\
0&0&-73&-50
\end{bmatrix}\implies
\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&0&0\\
0&1&0&0\\
0&0&2&-27\\
0&0&-50&-73
\end{bmatrix}\implies
\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&0&0\\
0&1&0&0\\
0&0&2&-1\\
0&0&-50&-723
\end{bmatrix}\implies
\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&0&0\\
0&1&0&0\\
0&0&-1&0\\
0&0&-645&-1396
\end{bmatrix}\implies
\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&0&0\\
0&1&0&0\\
0&0&1&0\\
0&0&0&1396
\end{bmatrix}$

However the computer says the answer is supposed to be
$$\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&0&0\\
0&1&1&0\\
0&0&1&0\\
0&0&0&610
\end{bmatrix}$$

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How did you get $-50$? And what are you doing in the next step? Why don't switch between the columns 2 and 3 and make 0 instead of 2?

Comment: @user26857 thanks for the help, that corrected it.